# JPA 2.1 stored procedure with temporary table

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures

I found some troubles with calling stored procedure using JPA 2.1.

Lets assume I've got procedure that looks like this

```
create procedure [_get_agreements_by_status]
@status int
as
begin

select
    iAgreementId
    ,sSignature
    ,iStatus
from agreement
where iStatus = @status

end
```

When I call procedure from apprication everythings work fine - i recieve my result set and i can move on.

Here is the snipped how it looks in Java

```
StoredProcedureQuery  query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("_get_agreements_by_status");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);   
query.execute();
```

So far so good. The problem starts when I need to use temporary table in my procedur. As soon I add temporary table to procedure I cant get result set.
What is more disturbing #table doesn't have to be a part of any query.

What am i doing wrong?

Database is MS SQL Server 2008, JPA 2.1, JDBC driver 4.0

Comment: `I can't get result set`. Which means what? some exception? JPA should be simply using JDBC CallableStatement, and?

Comment: When im calling procedure without #table query.hasMoreResult returns true and i can parse query.getResultList() to List. When procedure contains #table getResultList() returns null

Comment: and if you did the same using JDBC API ? which would then isolate the problem to the JDBC driver

Comment: If i do the same with JDBC for query without #teble it works fine, with #table i get following exception "Exception occurred in target VM: The statement did not return a result set."

Comment: Ok, probably i've found solution - there needs to be added 'SET NOCOUNT ON' in stored procedure. Just made a quick test and it looks promising.